# includeHTML conflicting with renderPlotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm creating a small app with shiny to show simulation results based on user input with plot_ly() (need plotly for animation). It utilizes navbarpage() to show a home page (where I explain the rationale) and a simulation page (where the app is actually displayed).

To create the homepage, I created a .Rmd file and knitted to html. Unfortunately, it appears that  `includeHTML()` and `renderPlotly()` have some sort of javascript conflict and so plotly will not render. Double unfortunately, I know almost nothing about HTML or javascript.

A simple (almost reprex) version:

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("RCV", position = "fixed-top", collapsible = TRUE,
    tabPanel("Home",
             includeHTML("www/yourFav.html")),
    tabPanel("Simulation",
             plotlyOutput("plot")
  )

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(data = cars,
            x = ~mgp,
            y = ~wt)
  })

}
```

Any suggestions you have will be well received!

Best,
Brennan

Comment: One uses `includeHTML` for HTML "fragments": only the contents of the `<body>` of a full HTML. To include a full HTML, use `tags$iframe`.

Comment: Hi @StéphaneLaurent,  thanks for the feedback. When using tags$iframe, i just get an empty box at the top left corner. The full Rmd/HTML file can be found here (https://github.com/btbeal/RankedChoiceVoting/tree/master/www/HomePage) if it helps.

Comment: @ Brennan, perhaps it's because you have to set a width and a height ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent just a larger blank box. I've used iframes in the past to import shiny objects to HTML... but not the other way around. If it means anything, the html was rendered from Rmd. I guess i can try to custom build one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includeHTML` is intended to be used for HTML fragments. Use an `iframe` for a full HTML page. The HTML file must be in the **www** subfolder, and you have to pass it to the `src` argument of `tags$iframe` without the `www/` prefix.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("RCV", position = "fixed-top", collapsible = TRUE,
             tabPanel("Home",
                      tags$iframe(src = "rcv_homePage.html", 
                                  width = "600", height = "500", 
                                  style = "margin-top: 70px;")),
             tabPanel("Simulation",
                      plotlyOutput("plot")
             )

  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(data = cars,
            x = ~mgp,
            y = ~wt)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You are a friend and a scholar. This works perfectly.